# Not able to open WSDL in browser

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, tomcat, wsdl

I created a simple java program like below,

```
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public class testing {
public static void main(String args[]){
    System.out.println("hiiii");
}
}
```

Then i created a web service from this in eclipse which was

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="testingService" targetNamespace="http://service.xms.com/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://service.xms.com/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">
  <wsdl:portType name="testing">
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="testingServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:testing">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="testingService">
    <wsdl:port name="testingPort" binding="tns:testingServiceSoapBinding">
      <soap:address location="h..p://loca...st:8080/XMSExpenseServicePROD/services/testingPort"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Now when i open h..p://loca...st:8080/XMSExpenseServicePROD/services/testingPort?wsdl in browser, it gives me 404 error, The requested resource is not available... What is wrong in my program here or where i am going wrong. Plese help.

This is not the exact issue, issue was in a different project but after investigation i found, i am not able to even open this url in browser which is generated by eclipse. I am not able to figure out where i am going wrong. Can anyone help?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is:

`<soap:address location="h..p://loca...st:8080/XMSExpenseServicePROD/services/testingPort"/>`

actually defined in your xml with that URL? If you are omitting any of your config, can you post the whole config?

What is running on localhost:8080, is this from Tomcat? Do you have the tomcat log output?

What's the project directory structure?

Comment: I have edited and added the configs, and this soap address is from the generated wsdl. Yes i am using tomcat server...Tomcat log is ----> 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [07/Aug/2013:16:51:05 -0400] "GET /XMSExpenseServicePROD/WEB-INF/classes/com/xms/service/XmsExpenseServiceImpl.java HTTP/1.1" 404 1111

Comment: type Status report

message /XMSExpenseServicePROD/services/xmsexpenseservice

description The requested resource is not available.

Comment: @nisha: I used the following guide to create a WSDL service in Eclipse: http://vimeo.com/7905480.
One thing I noticed is that your class you are trying to create a WSDL from has a public static void main(String[] args) method. I'm not sure if you can return void from a WSDL method or not. I didn't need to create the annotation for the service to work though. Creating a class `com.test.wsdltestproject.TestService` with a method `public String testMesssage() { return "Hiii"; }` worked and generated the following URI: http://localhost:8080/WsdlTestProject/services/TestService.

Comment: @nisha: After validating that your project is running in Tomcat, what page do you see if you navigate to: http://localhost:8080/XMSExpenseServicePROD/services/testingPort (no ?wsdl). If your XML has the .s in there, you probably had an issue when it was being generated and may need to fix it.

Comment: Thanks @anonymous  .. Your comments gave me an idea, i created a new dynamic web proj and copied all the content and was able to open the wsdl in browser.